# AWS Code pipeline Manual Approval Timeout

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to change maximum duration of manual approval actionin AWS Code pipeline? currently it's defaulted to 7 days by AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request an AWS ticket to increase the approval action limits.
[AWS Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/limits.html)

Comment: I think the limit has been set up at a product level, not sure if they could increase it for a requirement.

Comment: Is there any configuration parameter for it?

Comment: There is no configuration parameter but they can increase the limit if you request for it!

Comment: That is in the section that specifically says: "These quotas are fixed and cannot be changed." So no, you can't request a change of that value.